# Проверьте знаки препинания, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация

И потому, я не могу научить никого из вас взбираться... - перед "потому" нужна запятая?

Для всех нас она личная - тут нужны в принципе какие-то знаки (например, тире перед "она")?

Правда в том, что, возвращаясь сюда раз за разом, она выглядит совсем иначе в отличие от прошлых подъёмов - тут нужна запятая после "что" или оно входит в состав причастного оборота?

Comment: Вопрос оформлен некорректно. 1. Обычно каждое предложение — это отдельный вопрос.  2. Предложение должно быть полное, с ясным смыслом (не в виде фрагментов). В некоторых случаях для ясности даже требуется контекст. 3. В последнем предложении неточная грамматика: проверьте сочетаемость слов "иначе" и "в отличие от" 4. Желательно высказать собственное мнение по поводу знаков препинания.  Всё остальное мы можем проверить (грамматику, стилистику, правописание).

Comment: Просто видела, что в некоторых постах спрашивают сразу несколько предложений, да и мне так проще. В последнем предложении имеется в виду, что она выглядит иной, в отличие от и т.д (тоже теперь стало непонятно нужа здесь запятая или нет). Здесь идёт речь о лестнице, и говоря для всех она личная, имеется в виду жизненый путь, там контекст особо не поможет.  Первое предложение по тексту сразу идёт после второго.

Comment: Предшествующие предложения, идущие перед "Для всех нас она личная": Лестница для всех разная.
Может, когда я впервые взбиралась на неё, мой путь был не таким страшным, как ваш. Для всех нас она личная. И потому, я не могу научить никого из вас взбираться... Ведь мой путь не похож на ваш. (не понимаю нужно ли тире после она - личная или там нужна запятая) ( не понимаю нужна ли запятая после и потому)

Answer (score 1):

Это мой вариант правки (интересный у вас текст):

*Лестница для всех разная. Может, когда я впервые **поднималась**  на неё, мой путь был не таким страшным, как ваш. **Для каждого – она личная.** **Поэтому** я не могу научить никого из вас взбираться... Ведь мой путь не похож на ваш. И еще правда в том, что, возвращаясь сюда раз за разом, **я вижу ее иной, отличной от прошлых подъёмов**.*

Вы можете использовать этот текст или записать его как-то иначе, если я не совсем правильно поняла вашу мысль.

А это **ответы на вопросы.**

(1) **И потому...**  Наречие в начале предложения не обособляется (нет причин, это не вводное слово).

(2) **Для всех нас она личная.** Здесь возможно интонационное тире, если автор хочет обозначить паузу в том месте, где он ее слышит. Я поменяла структуру предложения: *Для кАждого – она личная.* При постановке тире предыдущее слово выделено логическим ударением.

(3) Последнее предложение **пришлось перестроить.** Дело в том, что субъект действия должен быть одним и тем же в сказуемом и в деепричастном обороте (в вашем тексте: возвращаетесь вы, а выглядит она).

Comment: Огромное спасибо!